# Understanding Laravel caching: Cache facade and Redis

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I'm new to Laravel. I've done research on the topic, but I can't seem to find an answer that clears things up for me.

I know Laravel's default cache driver is set to *file*, which I can change. It also has some artisan cache commands, such as:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

**1)** Even if Laravel has some built-in commands and features that automatically handle some cache (didn't understand exactly what parts), I still have to manually use the Cache facade on query results, right?

It doesn't do it automatically, and I only have to use the Cache facade if I want to change things or something, right?

Here's a random example from a tutorial:

```
$posts = Cache::remember('index.posts', 30, function()
{return Post::with('comments', 'tags', 'author', 'seo')->whereHidden(0)->get();});
```

**2)** When using Redis (with the *predis* package) as the cache driver, do I need to use the Cache facade, or the Redis facade, or both in some cases? Or can I simply enable Redis in Laravel and server (Digital Ocean droplet on Forge) and don't do anything else?

I've seen something like this in the Laravel docs, using the Cache facade:

```
Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 600);
```

I've also seen a tutorial using the Redis facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis; 

Route::get('/', function () { 
     $visits = Redis::incr('visits'); 
     return $visits; 
});
```

I can't figure out what's the proper thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Common:

They are **all cache**.

They are all used to **reduce time cost**.

## Differenet:

---

### Configurations And Routes:

It belongs to **application**. We call it **Application Cache**.

```sh
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

These two commands is caching routes and configurations.

#### PATH:

> They are always stored in `bootstrap/cache/`

Running

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Only clear the directories and files in `bootstrap/cache/`.

They are **static**. So they are only changed when you changing them.

#### Benifit

If you change them, you need to `clear` and `cache` them manually.

After you cahce these routes and configurations.

Laravel **doesn't need to read the configurations and routes from file again** which took IO time cost.

---

### Filesystem Cache And Redis Cache:

Filesystem cache and Redis cache are both cache too.

However, they use **different driver** to store the datas, means **where you store the caching datas**.

> Filesystem PATH: If you are using filesystem driver. they are stored in `storage/framework/cache/`
>
> Reids PATH: Datas store in `redis` by key-value.

#### When do you use them?

When you found that there are many request to this code for getting datas.
And these datas is not changed so fast.

You can use cache to store them, and then, next time another request to this api.
it just take datas from the cache.
like below:

```php
$posts = Cache::remember('index.posts', 30, function()
{return Post::with('comments', 'tags', 'author', 'seo')->whereHidden(0)->get();});
```

The first request get the posts' datas from database, and then store the these datas in cache(Reids or Filesystem) expired after 30 sec.

Next request  get posts' datas only through cache. They don't need to search in databases again.

And this one:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis; 

Route::get('/', function () { 
     $visits = Redis::incr('visits'); 
     return $visits; 
});
```

Means when people request `localhost:8000/`, users' visit count increasing in `redis`(don't need to store in database, it cost more time),
next time, when request to search visit count, it can be found in `redis` very quickly.

> PS: Here use Redis Facade, then the datas are stored in `redis`.
>
> If you are using redis as cache driver, `Cache::remember()` will store datas in redis too.
>
> However, using Redis Facade, you can use many redis methods.

#### Which is better?

I think `redis` is better than `filesystem`.

1. Because `redis` store datas in memory, and filesystem store in disk.
   Read data from memory is **faster** than disk.
2. **Operate** datas in Redis is **easier** than Filesystem. For example Redis support clear all cache for a specific tag, but filesystem cannot[Because filesystem store cache datas by encrypted key's name].
3. For **distributed** server, filesystem cache is a bad idea. Lower cache hit ratio.

Honestly, there are other drivers can be choosed, like `mongodb`.

By the way, my English is not very good, hope u understand.

Comment: Ok, I understand now that I do have to use the Cache facade myself, at least if using the 'file' driver. Laravel won't automatically do some magic. Just to be 100% clear - do I have to do the same thing if using Redis as the driver? Do I still have to use the Cache or Redis facade on queries, as in my examples? Or it will just work out of the box on the server side? I looked at some Cloudways tutorials on Redis and Laravel, and they just say to enable Redis on the server and in Laravel, and that's it! This gets me thinking that I don't have to do anything else in my code. It just works.

Comment: @RaduB If you are using Redis, you just need to install redis in your server and run redis. And then change your driver configuration from ```file``` to ```redis```. Then when you use cache method, it automatically store datas to redis.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now. Even if I change the driver to Redis, I still need to use the Cache or Redis facade for my queries. The Cache facade can be used to store data in Redis, too, but it's best to use the Redis facade instead in order to take advantage of more Redis-related methods. Thank you! It helped a lot!