# Difference between Cache and Redis facade in laravel?

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I want to implement Cache system but i found tutorials where they use Cache facade but when i open Redis documentation they use Redis facade, is there difference or that is same thing?

Comment: Maybe can help u:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890788/understanding-laravel-caching-cache-facade-and-redis/58890968#58890968

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cache` facade lets you access the cache, so you can add/get/forget cache items. If you use redis as your cache driver this will use your redis instance as the cache store.

The `Redis` facade lets you access a redis connection, not the cache, although these may actually be the same redis instance depending on your config. This lets you access the pub/sub features of redis and interact with the redis instance using redis commands https://redis.io/commands

To get a better look at what the facades can do you can look at the classes they resolve to. The Cache facade resolves to `Illuminate\Contracts\Cache\Repository` and the Redis facade to `Illuminate\Redis\Connections\Connection`.

More info on what classes the facades resolve to at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/facades#facade-class-reference

Comment: Beware that Cache and Redis facades store data differently even if both use the same redis instance, you can't use them together. I figured out that using Cache::set('a','b');  stores the data actually as key:  "laravel:a"  value:   "s:8:\"b\";" , while Redis::set('a','b'); stores them as they are key:  'a' value  'b' . Use one of them not both.